# Blender physics simulation/animation not copying to Keyshot

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I'm very new to Blender.

I'm trying to export a simple fluid animation into KeyShot, but haven't had much succeess

I tried creating an animation with a sphere moving around, and it worked,
however, when I introduce the fluid simulation, it doesn't seem to work.

The fluid moves fine in Blender, but when I export it (.abc) into KeyShot, the parts appear, but there is no keyframe/timeline of the motion
[image: Blender Animation set up]
[image: Imported KeyShot Result]

Blender File Attached
[image]

Comment: For Domain object you have to enable "Mesh" panel and Bake fluid sim.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. It worked :)